# How to email team members within Visual Studio Team Services when they use Microsoft Accounts

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-devops

I am adding a user who has a Hotmail account to Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online).

First I added him to Azure Active Directory, then I added him to the Team in Visual Studio Team Services.

When I open a backlog item, and attempt to email it to him using the Team Services "Send Work Items in Email" feature, I get this error:

"Unable to send message to the following recipients: abc@hotmail.com Preferred Email address is not configured within the user’s profile."

Why doesn't it just use the Hotmail address? Looking through VSTS and Azure, I see no place to specify a "Preferred Email address". Google turns up very little, except Robert Noack's [post](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2230603/can-not-edit-profile-email-to-recieve-alerts-on-account-linked-to-msdn-account-with-different-email-address) on Microsoft Connect which describes trouble changing the Preferred Email for ADFS accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask the user to sign in VSTS to configure it. If it is the first time to login, a page will be displayed to ask him configure this. Otherwise, clicking the account name in the up right corner after login and select "My Profile->edit your profile".
[image]

Comment: This isn't quite the screen I received when logging in with my Microsoft Account.  Mine just said "Contact Email", and it wasn't clear whether that would change my Live account, or just the VS login.  I am going to take your word for it though.  Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Even though this works, it is still confusing, as in the email received it comes the Live Account email, instead of the email configured as preferred contact: "Your Name (username@outlook.com) sent you a work item."